# NULL Filter against FullTextSQLQuery Search Query in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: fulltextsqlquery

I need to get results from scope where `DueDate` is not `NULL`.
I applied Condition for this.
here is the code for getting results from scope, but when I apply condition for `DueDate`, an exception is thrown.

I applied the condition like this -> `DueDate IS NOT NULL`

**Code**

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("SiteCollectionURL"))
{
    FullTextSqlQuery myQuery = new FullTextSqlQuery(siteCollection)
    {
        RowLimit = 1000,
        QueryText = "SELECT ID, Title, AssignedTo, DueDate, Created FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'My Scope' AND DueDate IS NOT NULL",
        ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults

    };
    ResultTableCollection queryResults = myQuery.Execute();
    ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
    DataTable objDatatable= new DataTable();
    objDatatable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
}
```

**Inner Exception**

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80044100

**Stack trace**

> Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(ISearchServiceApplication
>   serviceApplication) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation1
>   webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String
>   operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation1 webServiceCall)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute() at
>   MyMethos.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.MyMethos()

I also tried with `DueDate <> ''`

Any alternative solution for filtering `null` values?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://blog.mastykarz.nl/excluding-empty-text-values-sharepoint-search/ you might try **DueDate > ''**

> What I’ve found out by trial and error is that changing the IS NOT
>   NULL predicate to > ‘’ works! 
>   `SELECT Tags FROM portal..scope() WHERE "SCOPE" = 'My scope' AND Tags > ''`
>  
>   After having modified the query as
>   displayed above, the query returned results as expected. So if you
>   ever find yourself having troubles with NULL values, the above might
>   perhaps help you as well.

Comment: I already tried this...
Getting error like your query is malformed.

Comment: If the Managed Property is a DateTime value that may indeed fail. I'm afraid what you're trying to do might just be impossible.

Comment: my first query which returns data if duedate is not null and other conditions,
second query is if duedate is null and other conditions,

Finally i need to merge two results from these queries.